# Keeping A Collection Of Generic Objects

Tags: c#, generics

In my application, I have a `WebManager` which makes web calls and executes a callback when for each one when complete. The object passed to the callback depends on the particular web call being made, and therefor is generic. Simplified, it looks something like this:

```
public struct CommandParam<T> where T : DtoBase, new()
{
    public DtoBase command;
    public Action<T> onSuccess;
    public Action onFailure;
    public WWW www;
}
```

When a web call succeeds, the text is deserialized in the correct response class:

```
response = (T) JsonReader.Deserialize(commandParams.www.text, typeof(T));
commandParams.onSuccess(response);
```

But when a web call fails, I want to queue the relevant `CommandParam<T>`. Upon the next web call, or an explicit instruction, the queue will be processed, if possible. I'm envisioning a simple queue:

```
private static Queue<CommandParam<DtoBase>> failedCommandQueue;
```

The problem is, I obviously can't add any old `CommandParam<T>` to the queue. Further, a `CommandParam<T>` can't be casted to a `CommandParam<DtoObject>`.

So my question is a search for ways to handle this situation appropriately. My most recent thought was to do some dynamic boxing/unboxing:

```
private struct BoxedCommand
{
    public Type type;
    public Object commandParam;
}

private static Queue<BoxedCommand> failedCommandQueue;
```

But I don't know that it's possible to actually do the unboxing since at some point it's going to require using `type` to cast the `commandParam` (e.g. `(type) commandParam`).

Comment: So, you're queuing up failures until a success happens and then sending them back with the success event?  (Under persistent failure, this seems a dismal situation)  Note: Putting the failures into a transmittable package does seem helpful.

Comment: I may not have explained it well. If a web call fails, it gets added to the queue. Then, when the next web call occurs, the containing class will attempt to resend each item in the queue. If successful, the items will be removed from the queue. If not, they will stay in the queue until the next opportunity. The success event will only fire if the web call was actually successful. Regarding persistent failure, failed web calls will only stack up for a single session. The calls are very small so memory issues are highly unlikely.

Comment: ah, ok.  so it's more "retries" than "failures" that are stacking up and they're to be re-processed rather than returned to caller.

Comment: I'm a little lost.  You said 'The problem is, I obviously can't add any old CommandParam<T> to the queue'  But you have a `where T : DtoBase` - So no, with that there you can't.  Then you say 'Further, a CommandParam<T> can't be casted to a CommandParam<DtoObject>.' - Why?  How are you trying to do this?  Also, could you throw up your DtoBase & CommandParam objects?  I'd be happy to help if you can give me this extra information :)